# Promise.all does not wait for all the promise to finish firestore data read

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have below data structure that will be added to the firestore `collection` as `document`

```
{
    ".......": "......." //few more properties
    "productInfo": {
        "0": {
            "code": "SC05",
            "price": 400,
            "productId": "asUsd1HPEPOo2itiKxdash",
            ".......": "......." //few more properties
            "addOns": [{
                    "aid": "4casedasgdfdgfas",
                    "price": "50",
                    "......": "....." //few more properties
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

So I will be having array of products object and each product will have array of addon object.

I am trying to retrieve price from db before saving it as document and hence I've written `.onCreate` function for that particular table. To retrieve price on the `product` level and `addon` level, I am having 2 promises as below:

```
const productPromises = [];
_.map(products, (product) => {
    productPromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.doc(`product/${product.productId}`).get().then(docData => {
            return resolve({
                productId: product.productId,
                halfkgprice: docData.data().halfkgprice,
                price: docData.data().price
            });
        }).catch(reason => {
            return reject(reason);
        });
    }));
});

const addonPromise = [];
_.map(products, (product) => {
    addonPromise.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (product.addOns !== undefined && product.addOns !== null) {
            return _.map(product.addOns, (addon) => {
                return db.doc(`addons/${addon.aid}`).get().then((addonData) => {
                    return resolve({
                        price: addonData.data().price
                     });
                }).catch(reason => {
                    return reject(reason);
                })
            });
         } else {
            return resolve();
        }
     }));
 });
```

and then I do have

```
Promise.all([productPromises, addonPromise]).then(result => {
      //do something with result
});
```

But this will not wait any of the promise to resolve. When I log the result I get as below.

```
console.log(result) will show [ [ Promise { <pending> } ], [ Promise { <pending> } ] ] and doesn't wait for them to resolve
```

My question is, why is not waiting for all the promises to resolve? Is there any problem with the way I am returning data from `firestore` get `query`?

Comment: productPromises and addonPromise are arrays of promises, so the array you pass to Promise.all is an array of arrays, not an array of promises - try `Promise.all([...productPromises, ...addonPromise]).then`

Comment: Why are you creating a new Promise object when you already have one that's returned from get().then().catch()?

Comment: @DougStevenson I didn't get you.

Comment: @JaromandaX Trying that. Few moment please.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - he means [Avoid the promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: They are 2 different arrays, so you need to merge them to one array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`productPromises` and `addonPromise` are arrays of promises, so the array you pass to `Promise.all` is an array of arrays, not an array of promises - try

```
Promise.all([...productPromises, ...addonPromise]).then
```

Also, avoid the Promise constructor anti-pattern

```
_.map(products, (product) => {
    productPromises.push(
        db.doc(`product/${product.productId}`).get().then(docData => {
            return ({
                productId: product.productId,
                halfkgprice: docData.data().halfkgprice,
                price: docData.data().price
            });
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Awesome bro. Thank you so much. It helped much.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to concat 2 arrays to make it work as expected

```
Promise.all(productPromises.concat(addonPromise)).then(result => {
      //do something with result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` builds an array of returned values, so you can just write:

```
  const productPromises = _.map(products, product => db.doc(`product/${product.productId}`).get()
       .then(docData => ({
            productId: product.productId,
            halfkgprice: docData.data().halfkgprice,
            price: docData.data().price
        })
  );
```

Comment: Well this looks still easy. Could you please let me know if this is better than current approach and if yes how? I am just beginner in understanding `promises` so I would like to know.. :)

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map to understand how map works. How you are using it is like a .forEach() call. But underneath it is still creating an array of [undefined, undefined, undefined...] (because you are not returning anything in the map function), which you then discard. Once you use map() as intended, it actually makes things simpler. :)